# Cannot draw rect on QPixmap with QPainter

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I have a problem with drawing a rect on QPixmap, which I loaded from file.  And I also want to use this pixmap as a icon in listView.

#### Code:

```
QPixmap pixmap(100, 100);//(temp);// = QPixmap(temp);

pixmap.load(temp);

QPainter* painter = new QPainter(&pixmap);
painter->setPen(QPen(Qt::blue, 4, Qt::SolidLine));
painter->drawRect(4, 4, 50, 50);
painter->end();
QIcon icon = QIcon();

icon.addPixmap(pixmap);
```

`temp` is a QString path to the file. It shows only a resized photo without rect. When I commented a line with load, then rect is shown with random background.

or maybe someone know how to do this with `QIcon::paint` function.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide code where you use icon?

Comment: something like this: `QListWidgetItem * item = new QListWidgetItem(icon, "");item->setData(Qt::UserRole, i);
ui.listWidget->addItem(item);`

Comment: your code works here, the blue rect is drawn, there is nothing that seems wrong with it other than the possible memory leak of `QPainter` (you don't delete it after you are done with it, also note that you can create it on the stack no need for it to be created on the heap).

Comment: I've tried to do QPainter as a class memeber and create it in constructor of window. Then I use `painter->begin(&pixmap)` but it's still doesn't work. It's all inside loops and slot so there is probably a problem.

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce. You should have the painter by value, not by pointer, but that doesn't change the fact that it works: `QPixmap pixmap; pixmap.load(filename); QPainter painter{&pixmap}; ...`

Comment: You should check the boolean returned by Pixmap::load(). Theres a big chance that it's not working for you because the path is incorrect.

Comment: Path is correct because there is a orginal photo in icon. I've done it's another way: I used function `QPainter::drawImage` on some background `QPixmap` and get rect on borders of icon. But I still don't know where was my problem there. Thank you guys anyway.